# Issue with setting up Content Source

Tags: search, crawling

Does anyone know if it's possible to set up a content source to index a site that uses browser based login?

I have tryed a few things and can't seem to get it to work, including having the username / password part of the URL for the start address but SharePoint strips it out.

The error I get is 'Access is denied' however the default content access account has full permissions to the site.

Enviroment:
SharePoint Enterprise 2010

More Clarification:

The web application that we want SharePoint to index is hosted on Apache using Web Server Authentication. When we add the username and password of the content access account to the URL and use the browser to navigate to it, it logs in fine. However when we set up the content source to use the same URL, the username and password are removed from the path and SharePoint fails to authenticate.
Sample URL: http://Username:Password@siteurl

Answer (score 1):

For form based authentication sites you need to extend your web application to a new zone/AAM whith an IIS that uses NTLM.

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276323.aspx) is a guide on how to extend a webapp.

When site is extended (use an internal url) you create a content source for this url.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added some more info to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use forms login or use a different set of credentials from the crawl account you need to configure a Crawl Rule. This is separate from configuring your content sources.

Each crawl rule has a prefix or regular expression to define the URLs to which it applies. The two functions of the crawl rules are to allow you to exclude certain URLs from your crawl, and secondly to define the credentials you want to use to access URLs that you do want to crawl.